# How to add elements in array?

Tags: java, arrays

See the code for example:

```
public Core()
{   
    class1 = new int[5]; //declares array for 5 class 
    class2 = new int[5]; //delcares array for 5 class

    System.out.println("Please type 1 for First Classe:");
    select = input.nextInt();

    if(select == 1)
    {

    }

}
```

Alright. If the user select the option number 1, occupy an place of the in the memory of array. For example:

```
class1 = new int[4];
```

Or, if case exceed the memory appears one message.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add elements to an array - they're a fixed size after creation. I suspect you'd be better off with a `List` implementation of some description, such as `ArrayList`.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, to be honest - but it's almost certain that using a collection instead of an array would make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an ArrayList?

```
import java.util.*; 
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

ArrayLists have dynamic size, so you can add and take away members of the array during runtime.

```
list.add(someObject); //add object
list.remove(2); //remove object by index, objects will 'slide' down to fill the gap
int size = list.size(); //get size of ArrayList
String object = list.get(3) //get object in array, not always string
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks by respond!
But, no I'm using the import ArrayList. I'm creating so :

int[] class1; //declares an array of integers
int[] class2;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [`java.util.List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead?

```
List<List<Integer>> classes = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
classes.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
classes.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

// Assume the user inputs 1.
int select = 1;

// Retrieve the list and add values to the list.
List<Integer> theClass = classes.get(select);
theClass.add(someValue);
..
theClass.add(someValueN);    

// And from your question you wanted some restriction on the size, 
// so you deal with that here, for instance.
if (theClass.size() > 5) {
  System.err.println("Size exceeded!");
  for (int i = theClass.size() - 1; i >= 5; i--) {
    theClass.remove(i);
  }
}

// Print them out.
for (int i = 0; i < theClass.size(); i++) {
  // The difference to your comment is actually referencing 
  // all entries with the index 'i'.
  System.out.println(theClass.get(i));
}
```

Note that it is, of course, better not to add the element if you're later going to remove it again. But this is just a simple illustration of the idea.

Comment: Still I'm with problem. I desire add an number within of array, for example:


  if(select == 1)
  {
   
   class1[0] = 1;
    
  }

  System.out.println("Class1: ");
  
  int i = 0;
  while(i <= class1.length)
  {
   System.out.println(class1[0]);
   i++;
  }

Result:

Class1: 
1
1
1
1
1
1


Why ? I want add one number in only one memory. See, this add all memory.

Comment: Well, you are only assigning to index=0 and you are only ever printing out `class1[0]` (index=0). Instead, your print could be `System.out.println(class1[i]);`. But instead of doing that you should have to 'ArrayList`s and add to them. I'll write an example in my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to insert elements in the array until it is full.

The one you declared is not a dynamic array but a static one. This means that once you declared `int[] class1 = new int[5]` you will have just 5 slots and you will have to take care where you insert them.

```
class1[0] = value
```

This one inserts the value in the first slot of the array, while next one:

```
class1[5] = something
```

would be wrong because you are trying to set the sixth element of an array with size 5. What you need to do is to add elements until you fill the array. You can do it by having an **index** value that keeps track of the current position:

int index = 0;
int[] class1 = new int[5];

```
....
if (index < class1.length)
  class1[index] = value
else
  //ARRAY IS FULL!
```

or you can check the array itself:

```
int i = 0;
boolean placed = false;
while (i < class1.length && class1[i] != null)
  ++i;
if (i < class1.length)
  class1[i] = value;
else
  //ARRAY IS FULL!
```

But my suggestion is to definitely **use an `ArrayList`, and keep maximum size as a variable.**