# How do I add an element to the end of my array?

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know if this is right, so I need your comments guys. I have an array of employee names. It will be displayed on the console, then will prompt if the user wants to insert another name. The name should be added on the end of the array(index 4) and will display again the array but with the new name already added. How do I do that? Btw, here's my code. And I'm stuck. I don't even know if writing the null there is valid.

```
public static void list() {
    String[] employees = new String[5];
    employees[0] = "egay";
    employees[1] = "ciara";
    employees[2] = "alura";
    employees[3] = "flora";
    employees[4] = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(employees[i]);
    }
}
public static void toDo() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    System.out.println("1 Insert");
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    if(choice == 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: You should use another structure, for example, java.util.ArrayList, instead of array.
The size of array is immutable, but ArrayList is mutable.
If you only want to use array, you must recreate array, but i thing 
another structure is best choice

Comment: You should use an `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: This is basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939154/how-to-add-elements-in-array

Answer (score 5):

You can't, basically.

Arrays have a fixed size when they've been constructed. You *could* create a new array with the required size, copy all the existing elements into it, then the new element... or you could use a `List<String>` implementation instead, such as `ArrayList<String>`. I'd strongly advise the latter approach.

I suggest you read the [collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) to learn more about the various collections available in Java.

Also note that you've currently just got a *local* variable in the `list` method. You'll probably want a *field* instead. Ideally an instance field (e.g. in a class called `Company` or something similar) - but if you're just experimenting, you could use a `static` field at the moment. Static fields represent *global state* and are generally a bad idea for mutable values, but it looks like at the moment all your methods are static too...

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are fixed in size. Once you declare you can not modify it's size.

Use Collection `java.util.List` or `java.util.Set`. Example `ArrayList` which is dynamic grow-able and backed by array.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use arrays then you will have to increase the size of the array by using an intermediate copy.

```
String[] array = new String[employees.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(employees, 0, array, 0, employees.length);
array[employees.length] = newName;
employees = array;
```

However, the best way would be to use a `List` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the user can enter more than 4 employee names.  If they can then using ArrayList is the better choice.  Also the employees variable needs to be a static property of your class since being used in a static method.

```
private static String[] employees = new String[5];

static {
    employees[0] = "egay";
    employees[1] = "ciara";
    employees[2] = "alura";
    employees[3] = "flora";
    employees[4] = null;
}

public static void list() {
    for(int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(employees[i]);
    }
}

public static void addEmployeeName(String name, int index) {
    employees[index] = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using static array which is fixed at the time of creation.I think you should use 
java.util.Arraylist which will provide you facility of dynamic array.